# Is there a VBA function for re-ordering lat/long data within a string to be long/lat?

Tags: vba, gis

I have several thousand rows of coordinate data in the form `Lat:Long,Lat:Long,Lat:Long...`. I am trying to switch it to be `Long:Lat,Long:Lat,Long:Lat...` using VBA. The strings are various lengths (~10 sets of coords to 100s of sets). Some example data below.

Shape 1  `28.6821:8.8784,28.6952:8.9015,28.701:8.9314,28.6109:8.9835,28.5894:8.9886,28.5577:8.9853,28.5518:8.9702,28.5482:8.9299,28.5821:8.9032,28.6078:8.8893,28.6366:8.8864,28.6543:8.8804,28.6821:8.8784`

Shape 2

```
25.8274:1.3314,25.812:1.3405,25.795:1.34,25.7715:1.3364,25.7524:1.3215,25.7294:1.2855,25.6917:1.2576,25.6608:1.2471,25.6425:1.2281,25.6349:1.2164,25.6376:1.1936,25.6466:1.1735,25.6704:1.1657,25.7048:1.1674,25.7255:1.1716,25.7458:1.1838,25.7602:1.2014,25.7671:1.2182,25.7745:1.2514,25.787:1.2668,25.8044:1.2703,25.8221:1.2904,25.8319:1.3129,25.8274:1.3314
```

Shape 3 `29.1414:2.2136,29.1469:2.2402,29.1263:2.2523,29.0886:2.2445,29.0525:2.2576,28.9879:2.2505,28.9624:2.2424,28.9445:2.2256,28.9576:2.2109,29.0346:2.2012,29.0385:2.178,29.0505:2.164,29.0698:2.1681,29.1105:2.192,29.1414:2.2136`

Shape long string example 56.6827:-112.717,56.6824:-112.717,56.6824:-112.7167,56.6824:-112.7165,56.6824:-112.7101,56.6824:-112.7035,56.6824:-112.697,56.6824:-112.6904,56.6824:-112.6899,56.6824:-112.6835,56.6824:-112.6769,56.6824:-112.6704,56.6824:-112.6638,56.6824:-112.6633,56.6824:-112.6569,56.6824:-112.6504,56.6824:-112.6438,56.6824:-112.6372,56.6824:-112.6367,56.6824:-112.6303,56.6824:-112.6238,56.6824:-112.6172,56.6824:-112.6106,56.6824:-112.6101,56.6824:-112.6037,56.6824:-112.5972,56.6824:-112.5906,56.6824:-112.584,56.6824:-112.5836,56.6824:-112.5772,56.6824:-112.5706,56.6824:-112.564,56.6824:-112.5575,56.6824:-112.5571,56.6824:-112.557,56.6824:-112.5506,56.6824:-112.544,56.6824:-112.5374,56.6824:-112.5309,56.6788:-112.5309,56.6752:-112.5309,56.6716:-112.5309,56.668:-112.5309,56.6644:-112.5309,56.6607:-112.5308,56.6571:-112.5308,56.6536:-112.5308,56.6533:-112.5308,56.6497:-112.5308,56.6461:-112.5308,56.6425:-112.5308,56.6389:-112.5308,56.6353:-112.5308,56.6317:-112.5308,56.6281:-112.5308,56.6244:-112.5308,56.6243:-112.5308,56.6206:-112.5308,56.617:-112.5308,56.6134:-112.5308,56.6098:-112.5308,56.6062:-112.5308,56.6026:-112.5308,56.599:-112.5308,56.5954:-112.5308,56.5952:-112.5308,56.5916:-112.5308,56.5879:-112.5308,56.5843:-112.5308,56.5807:-112.5308,56.5771:-112.5308,56.5735:-112.5308,56.5699:-112.5308,56.5663:-112.5308,56.5661:-112.5308,56.5625:-112.5308,56.5589:-112.5308,56.5552:-112.5308,56.5516:-112.5308,56.548:-112.5308,56.5444:-112.5308,56.5408:-112.5308,56.5372:-112.5308,56.537:-112.5308,56.5334:-112.5308,56.5298:-112.5308,56.5262:-112.5307,56.5226:-112.5307,56.5189:-112.5307,56.5153:-112.5308,56.5117:-112.5308,56.5082:-112.5308,56.508:-112.5308,56.508:-112.5341,56.508:-112.5346,56.5044:-112.5346,56.5008:-112.5345,56.4972:-112.5345,56.4936:-112.5345,56.49:-112.5345,56.4863:-112.5345,56.4827:-112.5345,56.4792:-112.5345,56.4791:-112.5345,56.4789:-112.5345,56.4753:-112.5345,56.4717:-112.5345,56.4681:-112.5345,56.4645:-112.5345,56.4609:-112.5345,56.4573:-112.5344,56.4537:-112.5344,56.4501:-112.5344,56.45:-112.5344,56.4499:-112.5344,56.4462:-112.5344,56.4426:-112.5344,56.439:-112.5344,56.4354:-112.5344,56.4318:-112.5344,56.4282:-112.5344,56.4246:-112.5344,56.4211:-112.5344,56.421:-112.5344,56.4208:-112.5344,56.4172:-112.5344,56.4135:-112.5344,56.4099:-112.5344,56.4063:-112.5344,56.4027:-112.5344,56.3991:-112.5344,56.3955:-112.5343,56.3919:-112.5343,56.3919:-112.5343,56.3917:-112.5343,56.3881:-112.5343,56.3844:-112.5343,56.3808:-112.5343,56.3772:-112.5343,56.3736:-112.5343,56.37:-112.5343,56.3664:-112.5343,56.3628:-112.5343,56.3628:-112.5343,56.3626:-112.5343,56.359:-112.5343,56.3553:-112.5343,56.3517:-112.5343,56.3481:-112.5343,56.3481:-112.5408,56.3481:-112.5473,56.3481:-112.5538,56.3481:-112.5603,56.3481:-112.5606,56.3481:-112.5671,56.3481:-112.5736,56.3481:-112.5801,56.3481:-112.5866,56.3481:-112.587,56.3481:-112.5935,56.3481:-112.6,56.3481:-112.6065,56.3481:-112.6129,56.3481:-112.6133,56.3481:-112.6198,56.3481:-112.6263,56.3481:-112.6328,56.3481:-112.6393,56.3481:-112.6396,56.3481:-112.6461,56.3481:-112.6526,56.3481:-112.6591,56.3481:-112.6656,56.3481:-112.6659,56.3481:-112.6724,56.3481:-112.6789,56.3481:-112.6854,56.3481:-112.6919,56.3481:-112.6922,56.3481:-112.6987,56.3481:-112.7053,56.3481:-112.7118,56.3481:-112.7181,56.3481:-112.7186,56.3481:-112.7251,56.3481:-112.7316,56.3481:-112.7381,56.3481:-112.7444,56.3481:-112.7449,56.3481:-112.7514,56.3481:-112.7579,56.3481:-112.7644,56.3481:-112.7708,56.3481:-112.7713,56.3481:-112.7778,56.3481:-112.7843,56.3481:-112.7908,56.3481:-112.7971,56.3481:-112.7976,56.3481:-112.8041,56.3481:-112.8106,56.3481:-112.8171,56.3481:-112.8235,56.3481:-112.8239,56.3517:-112.8239,56.3553:-112.8239,56.3589:-112.8239,56.3626:-112.8239,56.3628:-112.8239,56.3664:-112.8239,56.37:-112.8239,56.3736:-112.8239,56.3772:-112.8239,56.3808:-112.8239,56.3844:-112.8239,56.388:-112.8239,56.3916:-112.8239,56.3919:-112.8239,56.3954:-112.8239,56.399:-112.8239,56.4027:-112.8239,56.4063:-112.8239,56.4099:-112.8239,56.4135:-112.8239,56.4171:-112.8239,56.4207:-112.8239,56.4207:-112.8304,56.4207:-112.837,56.4207:-112.8435,56.4207:-112.8498,56.4207:-112.8503,56.4207:-112.8568,56.4207:-112.8633,56.4207:-112.8698,56.4207:-112.8761,56.4207:-112.8766,56.4207:-112.8831,56.4207:-112.8896,56.4207:-112.8961,56.4207:-112.9025,56.4207:-112.903,56.4207:-112.9095,56.4207:-112.916,56.4207:-112.9225,56.4207:-112.9288,56.4207:-112.9293,56.4207:-112.9358,56.4207:-112.9423,56.4207:-112.9488,56.4207:-112.9551,56.4207:-112.9556,56.4207:-112.9621,56.4207:-112.9686,56.4207:-112.9751,56.4207:-112.9815,56.4207:-112.982,56.421:-112.982,56.4245:-112.982,56.4281:-112.982,56.4317:-112.982,56.4353:-112.982,56.439:-112.982,56.4426:-112.982,56.4462:-112.982,56.4498:-112.982,56.4501:-112.982,56.4536:-112.982,56.4572:-112.982,56.4608:-112.982,56.4644:-112.982,56.468:-112.982,56.4717:-112.982,56.4753:-112.982,56.4789:-112.982,56.4792:-112.982,56.4827:-112.982,56.4863:-112.982,56.4899:-112.982,56.4935:-112.982,56.4971:-112.982,56.5007:-112.982,56.5043:-112.982,56.5079:-112.982,56.5079:-112.9823,56.5079:-112.9828,56.5082:-112.9828,56.5117:-112.9828,56.5153:-112.9828,56.5189:-112.9828,56.5225:-112.9828,56.5262:-112.9828,56.5298:-112.9828,56.5334:-112.9828,56.537:-112.9828,56.5373:-112.9828,56.5408:-112.9828,56.5444:-112.9828,56.548:-112.9828,56.5516:-112.9828,56.5516:-112.9894,56.5516:-112.996,56.5516:-113.0025,56.5516:-113.0089,56.5516:-113.0094,56.5516:-113.016,56.5516:-113.0225,56.5516:-113.0291,56.5516:-113.0355,56.5516:-113.036,56.5552:-113.036,56.5588:-113.036,56.5624:-113.036,56.5661:-113.036,56.5663:-113.036,56.5698:-113.036,56.5735:-113.036,56.5771:-113.036,56.5807:-113.036,56.5843:-113.036,56.5879:-113.036,56.5915:-113.036,56.5951:-113.036,56.5954:-113.036,56.5989:-113.036,56.6025:-113.036,56.6062:-113.036,56.6098:-113.036,56.6134:-113.036,56.617:-113.036,56.6206:-113.036,56.6242:-113.036,56.6242:-113.0355,56.6242:-113.0291,56.6242:-113.0225,56.6242:-113.016,56.6242:-113.0094,56.6242:-113.0089,56.6242:-113.0025,56.6242:-112.996,56.6242:-112.9894,56.6242:-112.9828,56.6242:-112.9823,56.6242:-112.9759,56.6242:-112.9694,56.6242:-112.9628,56.6242:-112.9563,56.6242:-112.9558,56.6242:-112.9494,56.6242:-112.9428,56.6242:-112.9362,56.6242:-112.9297,56.6242:-112.9292,56.6242:-112.9228,56.6242:-112.9162,56.6242:-112.9096,56.6242:-112.9031,56.6242:-112.9026,56.6242:-112.8962,56.6242:-112.8896,56.6242:-112.8831,56.6242:-112.8765,56.6245:-112.8765,56.628:-112.8765,56.6316:-112.8765,56.6352:-112.8765,56.6388:-112.8765,56.6425:-112.8765,56.6461:-112.8765,56.6497:-112.8765,56.6533:-112.8765,56.6536:-112.8765,56.6571:-112.8765,56.6607:-112.8765,56.6643:-112.8765,56.6679:-112.8765,56.6715:-112.8765,56.6752:-112.8765,56.6788:-112.8765,56.6824:-112.8765,56.6827:-112.8765,56.6862:-112.8765,56.6898:-112.8765,56.6934:-112.8765,56.697:-112.8765,56.7006:-112.8765,56.7042:-112.8765,56.7079:-112.8765,56.7115:-112.8765,56.7117:-112.8765,56.7153:-112.8765,56.7189:-112.8765,56.7225:-112.8765,56.7261:-112.8765,56.7297:-112.8765,56.7333:-112.8765,56.7369:-112.8765,56.7406:-112.8765,56.7408:-112.8765,56.7443:-112.8765,56.748:-112.8765,56.7516:-112.8765,56.7552:-112.8765,56.7588:-112.8765,56.7624:-112.8765,56.766:-112.8765,56.7696:-112.8765,56.7696:-112.876,56.7696:-112.8696,56.7696:-112.863,56.7697:-112.8565,56.7697:-112.8499,56.7697:-112.8494,56.7697:-112.843,56.7697:-112.8365,56.7697:-112.8299,56.7697:-112.8233,56.7697:-112.8228,56.7697:-112.8164,56.7697:-112.8099,56.7697:-112.8033,56.7697:-112.7968,56.7697:-112.7963,56.7697:-112.7899,56.7697:-112.7833,56.7697:-112.7767,56.7697:-112.7702,56.7697:-112.7697,56.7697:-112.7633,56.7697:-112.7567,56.7697:-112.7501,56.7697:-112.7436,56.7697:-112.7431,56.7697:-112.7367,56.7697:-112.7301,56.7696:-112.7236,56.7696:-112.717,56.766:-112.717,56.7624:-112.717,56.7588:-112.717,56.7552:-112.717,56.7516:-112.717,56.748:-112.717,56.7444:-112.717,56.7408:-112.717,56.7406:-112.717,56.7369:-112.717,56.7333:-112.717,56.7297:-112.717,56.7261:-112.717,56.7225:-112.717,56.7189:-112.717,56.7153:-112.717,56.7117:-112.717,56.7115:-112.717,56.7079:-112.717,56.7042:-112.717,56.7006:-112.717,56.697:-112.717,56.6934:-112.717,56.6898:-112.717,56.6862:-112.717,56.6827:-112.717

Comment: split on the `,` iterate that array.  split on the `:` and concatenate in new order, then concatenate or join the outer loop.

Comment: There is; [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) and [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function). You will just have to do your bit too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR() As String
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Set Ws = Sheets(1) '<~~ Data sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) '<~~ Result sheet

    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    
    For i = 1 To r
        vR(i, 1) = "'" & getReOder(vDB(i, 1)) '<~~  Single quotes were added.
    Next i
    With toWs
        .Range("a1").Resize(r) = vR
    End With
        
End Sub
Function getReOder(v As Variant)
    Dim vSplit, v1, vS
    Dim a() As String
    Dim n As Integer
    
    vSplit = Split(v, ",")
    For Each v1 In vSplit
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve a(1 To n)
        vS = Split(v1, ":")
        a(n) = vS(1) & ":" & vS(0)
    Next v1
    getReOder = Join(a, ",")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for the majority of rows. I get an Out of Memory error (at  .Range("a1").Resize(r) = vR) when running it on multiple rows with a lot of coordinate pairs. Any ideas for how to get round this?  I have added an example of long strings to the original question. Thanks again.

Comment: @AFB27, When the-sign is first entered in the cell contents in Excel, it is recognized as a formula and does not exceed 8195 characters. So we need to recognize it as a character, so we put a single quote in front of the converted character. I edited my answer.